# What are 8086 ESC instruction opcodes

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, machine-code, instruction-encoding

Mostly of a historical interest and if I were to implement 8086 compatibility for assembler, what operands are considered valid for `ESC` instruction?

`ESC opcode, source`

From 8086 Programmer's manual I know, that `opcode` is an immediate in range 0 to 63 and `source` is a register or memory. But what registers can be encoded? Both `reg8` and `reg16` or only `reg16`? If `source` is memory, does operand size (`mem8` or `mem16`) matter?

Basically, both of the above don't really matter from instruction encoding perspective (as, for example, both `esc 0x01, ch` and `esc 0x01, bp` would produce the same result), but maybe assemblers had forced restrictions

And, the last, but not the least, where can I find description for `ESC` opcodes?

Comment: In x86 machine code terminology, there's a totally separate thing from what you're asking about but with a similar name: later CPUs use `0x0f` as an "escape *byte*" as the first byte of all 2-byte opcodes (for example [`cpuid`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cpuid) or some of the [new forms of imul added in 386](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul).)  See also http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html.  An "escape byte" is different from a "prefix", even a mandatory prefix that's part of the encoding of instructions like `pause` or `movss`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 8086 has an opcode space collectively designated `ESC` (escape to coprocessor). It occupies the range `d8` to `df`. Each instruction in this instruction space is followed by a modr/m byte and depending on the mod-field, zero to two displacement bytes. When the 8086 encounters an `ESC` instruction with two register operands (i.e. mod = 11), it performs a nop. When the processor encounters an `ESC` instruction with a memory operand, a read cycle is performed from the address indicated by the memory operand and the result is discarded.

Using two special signal lines, a coprocessor can distinguish data fetches from instruction fetches, allowing it to decode the instruction stream in parallel with the 8086.

This mechanism is used by the 8087 to hook into the instruction stream: The three available bits in the opcode byte together with the three bits of the reg field in the modr/m byte form a six bit opcode. The r/m field of the modr/m byte is used to designate either a location on the FPU register stack (if mod = 11, indicating two register operands) or a memory operand. Some opcodes encode a variety of instructions depending on the content of r/m field. In all these cases, one instruction is encoded for memory operands while eight other instructions are encoded for each possible register operand.

The 8087 registers when the 8086 performs the dummy fetch immediately after fetching the instruction and remembers the address. In case of an instruction that loads from memory, it loads the additional words of the memory operand and performs its function. In case of a store, it ignores the result of the fetch and stores its values to the address indicated by the 8086.

The 8087 performs operation asynchronously to the 8086.  However, no  implicit synchronization exists.  If an attempt is made to issue an `ESC` instruction while the coprocessor is busy, the instruction is silently ignored.  To solve this problem, the 8087 asserts its `BUSY` pin (connected to the 8086's `TEST` pin) while performing operation. The programmer can issue a `wait` instruction (`9b`, wait for coprocessor ready) to wait until the 8087 has concluded operation and consequently released the `WAIT` line. This is typically done before every single 8087 instruction and many assemblers of the day would automatically insert `WAIT` prefixes.  For high performance code, it was also common to instead manually calculate how long the 8087 was going to take for a certain instruction and to omit the `wait` when the previous floating point instruction was guaranteed to have finished.

Comment: "The 8087 registers when the 8086 performs the dummy fetch immediately after fetching the instruction and remembers the address" It took me some time to understand this sentence! I kept reading "8087 registers" as a noun, where you definitely meant the verb. Might I suggest "The 8087 records when ..." or "The 8086 marks when..." Others might have the same difficulty or not care at all.

Comment: Or perhaps "sees" or "keeps track of"? (Since "records" can also be a noun ;) )

Comment: One thing that bothers me, though, is how did the 8086 know how many bytes to skip after the opcode? If it was supposed to be completely ignorant about what the coprocessor is/does, it also shouldn't be involved in the process of decoding the number of opcode bytes for an (unknown) coprocessor. Did the 8086 also observe the 8087's operation to see how many bytes it fetched for its operands in order to skip them in its own program counter?

Comment: @SasQ The ESC opcodes all have the same format: one opcode byte followed by a modrm byte and if specified by the modrm byte, appropriate displacement bytes.

Comment: Re: `wait`, later CPU / FPUs like 386 / 387 didn't need to wait before every x87 instruction, only before  FPU => CPU stuff.  (Like `fstsw` is still [listed](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fstsw:fnstsw) with a `9B` prefix, with `fnstsw` for the raw instruction.)  Not relevant to 8086/87, but in case anyone was wondering why modern assemblers don't still do this, that's why.

Answer (score 2):

Opcodes for the 80x86 - like those of the predecessors the 8080 and 8085 - are best understood in octal, not hexadecimal. It's understood as 8 bits per byte with 2+3+3 bits, so the first octal digit ranges over 0-3, while the other two each range over 0-7.

The floating point escape has the octal form 33c xrm D, for Escape #c, with nominal register #r and operand mode (x,m), where D is one byte of the type int8_t for x = 1; 2 bytes of the type uint16_t for x = 2 or for (x,m) = (0,6); and 0 bytes otherwise.

For x = 3, m is nominally a second register: register #m, while for x = 0, 1 or 2 (except from (x,m) = (0,6)), m nominally denotes a combination of indexing registers (BX+SI, BX+DI, BP+SI, BP+DI, SI, DI, BP, BX) for m = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) respectively. The indexing is inapplicable for x = 3 (since m denotes a register, not a memory address) and is 0 or (x,m) = (0,6). The displacement is Disp = 0, if D is 0 bytes, Disp = (int16_t)D, if D is 1 byte; Disp = D, if D is 2 bytes.

Opcodes that are not supported trigger an exception in the CPU, as interrupt 6 - starting with the 80186.

I'm not sure exactly what handshaking goes on with the 33c opcodes nor what happens with interrupt 6, if anything. There's a hardware issue there, with synchronizing access to the data bus. For this purpose, the WAIT opcode (233) is present in the 8086 to allow the CPU to defer. An 8087 hooked up to the 8086 would do its thing before the 8086 resumed.

But for the 017 opcode and the other opcode-holes in the 8086, exception interrupt 6 gets triggered.

Whoever programs the bare-to-the-metal program for the CPU (by definition: The Firmware) is responsible for writing an exception-handler for interrupt 6 (and for all other interrupts and exceptions). The return address points to the *start* of the invalid operation, and this is done to give a hook for firmware to implement its own extensions of the opcode set.

There's nothing in the 80x86 language that gives a firmware programmer direct access to the "effective address" interpretation of (x,m,D) or "the register" for r, so they'd have to be explicitly interpreted in the firmware's exception-handler. But I think (x,m,D) drives the data bus at the hardware level, so that part of the task of interpretation is passed on to the hardware engineer. The task of interpreting "r", however, I think still has to be handled in firmware.

By the way, other places where the understanding implied by the octal format gets lost in the translation when people use hexadecimal for the opcodes, include the cases where the octal digit in the middle of an opcode encodes an operation.

What gets lost is that it's the same encoding that appears in various places. For instance, the opcodes 0pq denote operations (add, or, adc, sbb, and, sub, xor, cmp) for p = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) respectively; with different addressing modes q = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); cases q = (0, 1, 2, 3) taking on extra xrm D bytes, q = 4 takes on an extra 1-byte uint_8 value, and q = 5 an extra 2-byte uint_16 value.

It's the same "p" that occurs in the opcodes 20c xpm D, for c = (0, 1, 2, 3). So these have no register #r, as the r in xrm is replaced by the operator p. (Instead, they take on extra numeric bytes: 2 bytes for c = 2 and one byte for c = 0, 1 or 3). These are the "p" operations between the register or memory denoted by (x,m,D) and the extra 1 or 2 bytes of numeric data appended to the operation.

When I brought up the issue of the octal legacy the 8086, on the USENET, that prompted the creation of NASM (Netwide Assembler) in direct response, which is why it used - and still uses - octal internally for the opcodes.

Comment: `017` (0Fh) is a red herring here, the ESC opcodes are never considered invalid opcodes. But even so, `pop cs` aka `017` will not cause an interrupt 6 on all 8086 level processors because interrupt 6 was generally an 186-level facility.